# Xamarin Studio build targets? Trying to get Fody working?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get Xamarin Studio to use PropertyChanged.Fody.  I have Fody installed via NuGet which puts Fody.targets in its NuGet packages folder.  But when I build, the output never shows that the target is run.

How can I tell Xamarin Studio to use the Fody build target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and managed to figure out that if you remove the build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets from the csproj file Fody runs as normal.

So try and remove this line.

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
```

Comment: I know that you don't need Microsoft.Bcl.Build in Xamarin projects, but I need a explanation why Fody is working after removing this Import directive. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me hours!

Comment: Anyone got any thoughts on why this makes a difference?

Comment: For anyone still having issues, or requiring the BCL (e.g. if Microsoft.Http* is used), upgrading to Xamarin Studio 6.0, combined with this solution, was the fix in our case. Note that XS 6.0 has support for MSBuild tools v14; Fody is back into our app again.

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged your question with [monotouch](/questions/tagged/monotouch), I assume you're having the issue on iOS. Until very recently, `Xamarin.Studio` wasn't using xbuild (or msbuild) to build the project, and then additional targets were skipped.

Starting with `Xamarin.iOS 7.9` (or more realistically `8.0`), the default is unchanged but you have the option to enable it from the project preferences :

[image: use MSBuild build engine]

Ignore the "unsupported" warning, but know that it's unsupported if you have any issue.

Then, provided that the `nuget` correctly added a line like

```xml
  <Import Project="PATH_TO/Fody.targets" />
```

the target should be executed.

Comment: My solution consists of a PCL project for the shared components, an iOS project, and an Android project.  The files that need to have weaving happen to be in the PCL project.  That project does not have an option to select a build engine.

The iOS app does have that option, although checking it causes a build error suggesting it can't import Xamarin.MonoTouch.CSharp.targets.

Any recommenations given it's a shared library project?

Comment: Look at your build output, check if the task is executed

Comment: I've done that numerous times with various project option changes.  It never seems to execute.  I've double checked that the build target is imported in the csproj file, so it looks correct structurally.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the Fody.targets file. 
Just replace

```
Condition="Exists(@(IntermediateAssembly))"
```

with

```
Condition="Exists('@(IntermediateAssembly)')"
```

and it should work again.

Find the file in `.../projectfolder/packages/Fody2.x.x/build/netstandard1.4/Fody.targets`